# mysql constraint unique when boolean field is true

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

I have this table:

```
create table expert_country (
    expert_id  varchar(36) not null,
    country_id varchar(36) not null,
    main       boolean     not null default false,
    primary key (expert_id, country_id),
    constraint foreign key (expert_id) references expert (id),
    constraint foreign key (country_id) references country (id),
    -- constraint i'm looking for
);
```

But I can't figure out the constraint I need to add to have **only one main expert per country**.

I tried `constraint unique (country_id, true)` and `constraint unique (*, country_id, true)` but it is not valid sql.
Any ideas?

Comment: what about `constraint unique (country_id, main)`. so you can only have each country with true

Comment: I can have many experts for one country if they are not the main one. **only one main (=true) expert per country**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of unique keys ignoring `null` (which is following the sql standard): *any tuple containing `null` is not equivalent to any tuple.* That means, that in a unique index `(country_id, main)`, you can have the row `(1, null)` as often as you want, but at most one row `(1, 1)` and one row `(1, 0)`.

You would need to allow `null` for `main`, and would need to use `1` and `null` (not `0`) to encode if it is an expert or not (otherwise you can only have one non-expert). The constraint would then be:

```
main boolean null default null,
constraint unique index uidx_expert_country (country_id, main)
```

This might require changes to your application, might look sketchy (as `false` is obviously not the same as `null`) and might soften up the interpretation of your column (as it now can contain 3 values `null`, `0`/`false` and `1`/`true` although you can prevent that with an additional foreign key to a table with a single row containing `1`).

So if you do not want to do that, you can define an additional column that will be calculated in a trigger or as a generated column, and then define a unique index on that "dummy"-column:

```
main boolean  not null default false,
main_unq  boolean as (if(main = true,true, null)) stored,
constraint unique index uidx_expert_country (country_id, main_unq)
```

For a different way to encode the information which expert is the main expert of a country, you could e.g. add a column `main_expert_id` to your `country`-table (and a foreign key to `expert_country` to verify that the combination exists) and remove the column `main`.

Comment: I chose the `main_unq dummy column` solution and it works well. Thank you.