# Using trigger to check conditional uniqueness (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a MySQL table, that has a unique index constraint over multiple (2) columns: "username", and "provider". The index works fine and does not allow inserting rows with duplicated usernane+provider combination.

But I do want to allow insertion of the same usernane+provider combination in case another column, "active", has the value false. I do not have a problem with multiple duplicate rows all marked as active FALSE.
MySQL, unlike Microsoft SQL Server, does not support conditional/filterable indexing.

While I could not find a more appropriate solution, I thought to use a trigger (after insertion to the table) to check whether the value that was just inserted is duplicated, considering the "active" value.

Can I get the trigger to fail the INSERT statement? Is there a better solution for this case?

Comment: A unique index on usernane+provider is not going to be useful , consider a BEFORE insert trigger and abort using signal if required. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Try [mysql constraint unique when boolean field is true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51968200).